# Using Counter With Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python-3.x

How do I use counter for each value (list) in a dictionary? I would like the output to be key - value - count.

from collections import defaultdict, Counter

```
s = [('yellow', 'flower'), ('blue', 'water'), ('yellow', 'shirt'), ('blue', 
'sky'), ('red', 'lipstick'),('blue', 'water')]
d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)

print(d) 


defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'yellow': ['flower', 'shirt'], 'blue': ['water', 'sky', 'water'], 'red': ['lipstick']})
```

In the example above I would like the following output:
yellow - flower - 1
yellow - shirt - 1
blue - water - 2
blue - sky - 1
red - lipstick - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have a list of tuples which you want to count,

best to use built-in `Counter`:

```
from collection import Counter

s = [('yellow', 'flower'), ('blue', 'water'), ('yellow', 'shirt'), 
     ('blue', 'sky'), ('red', 'lipstick'),('blue', 'water')]
res = Counter(s)

print(res) 

>> Counter({('blue', 'water'): 2, ('yellow', 'flower'): 1, 
    ('yellow', 'shirt'): 1, ('blue', 'sky'): 1, ('red', 'lipstick'): 1})
```

It does the counting for you, don't worry about implementation

Comment: That works! I'm having trouble parsing through the multi-key dictionary, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: please share of input example

Comment: Sorry,
I'm attempting to create blue - water - 2, and trying:
' for k1, k2 in res:
    print(k1+" - "+k2) '

This gets blue - water easy enough but I'm baffled on how to get the 2

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, I forgot about items().

for k, v in res.items():
    print(k[0]+' - '+k[1] + ': ' + str(v))

Comment: That's even better! anyway, creating a list of tuples from a dict is indeed should be something like: `list(tuple({'a':1, 'b':2}))`